# Pagination with ability to hop on non adjacent page without offset limit

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I am using postgres, and trying to paginate the results.
The two standard methods failed to cater my needs which are

1. Offset Limit - because of cost at high offset
2. Seek - because of inability to jump on non adjacent pages

Then I came across ROW_NUMBER() method. The code is as below

```
DECLARE @row_per_page INT = 100
DECLARE @page_number INT = 2

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) AS [RowNumber],*
FROM table_name) AS T
WHERE T.[RowNumber] > (@page_number-1)*@row_per_page AND T.[RowNumber] < @page_number*@row_per_page+1
```

I am not understanding how this works, If I have a where condition for getting my results it will still search through whole database and then assign them unique row number, then selects some range of row_numbers. **Then how is it better than offset-limit?**. Can someone explain its working and performance?

Comment: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/

Comment: BTW Do you want to do it in Postgres (mentioned in the tags) or in the MS SQL (code in the question)?

Comment: I want in postgres, I could find code for it so posted mySql code for reference

Answer (score 2):

The code you quote above is actually worse than using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, because it does essentially the same thing by hand, and the code is complicated enough that PostgreSQL won't figure out that it could use a partial index scan or a *top-N heapsort*.

I'll show you an example:

```
\d large
     Table "laurenz.large"
┌────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ Column │  Type   │ Modifiers │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────┤
│ id     │ integer │ not null  │
│ val    │ text    │           │
└────────┴─────────┴───────────┘
Indexes:
    "large_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

This is what paging with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` does, depending on whether you have an index or not:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM large
ORDER BY val
OFFSET 50 LIMIT 10;
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52868.58..52868.60 rows=10 width=37)
        (actual time=1657.981..1658.001 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=8334
   ->  Sort  (cost=52868.45..55368.45 rows=1000000 width=37)
             (actual time=1657.909..1657.950 rows=60 loops=1)
         Sort Key: val
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
         Buffers: shared hit=8334
         ->  Seq Scan on large  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37)
                                (actual time=0.010..721.285 rows=1000000 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=8334
 Planning time: 0.078 ms
 Execution time: 1658.036 ms
```

Without index, PostgreSQL has to scan the whole table, but it can at least figure out that it only needs the first 60 rows.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM large
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 50 LIMIT 10;
                                        QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2.14..2.48 rows=10 width=37)
        (actual time=0.100..0.121 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Index Scan using large_pkey on large  (cost=0.42..34317.43 rows=1000000 width=37)
                                             (actual time=0.022..0.073 rows=60 loops=1
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning time: 0.130 ms
 Execution time: 0.158 ms
```

With an index, things are reasonably fast because the offset of 50 is small enough that it will not hurt so much.

Now let's try the same thing using `row_number`:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT id, val
   FROM (SELECT id, val,
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY val)
         FROM large
        ) q
   WHERE row_number BETWEEN 51 AND 60;
                                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on q  (cost=172682.84..205182.84 rows=5000 width=37)
                     (actual time=5663.090..10611.557 rows=10 loops=1)
   Filter: ((q.row_number >= 51) AND (q.row_number <= 60))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999990
   Buffers: shared hit=8334, temp read=9770 written=9770
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=172682.84..190182.84 rows=1000000 width=45)
                  (actual time=5662.803..9795.077 rows=1000000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=8334, temp read=9770 written=9770
         ->  Sort  (cost=172682.84..175182.84 rows=1000000 width=37)
                   (actual time=5662.784..8099.025 rows=1000000 loops=1)
               Sort Key: large.val
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 48848kB
               Buffers: shared hit=8334, temp read=9770 written=9770
               ->  Seq Scan on large  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37)
                                      (actual time=0.015..827.945 rows=1000000 loops=1
                     Buffers: shared hit=8334
 Planning time: 0.175 ms
 Execution time: 10621.032 ms
```

(14 rows)

PostgreSQL sorts the *whole* table, then scans the result and throws away everything but the rows needed.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT id, val
   FROM (SELECT id, val,
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)
         FROM large
        ) q
   WHERE row_number BETWEEN 51 AND 60;
                                          QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on q  (cost=0.42..64317.43 rows=5000 width=37)
                     (actual time=0.319..3411.027 rows=10 loops=1)
   Filter: ((q.row_number >= 51) AND (q.row_number <= 60))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999990
   Buffers: shared hit=11069
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..49317.43 rows=1000000 width=45)
                  (actual time=0.040..2585.197 rows=1000000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=11069
         ->  Index Scan using large_pkey on large (cost=0.42..34317.43 rows=1000000 width=37)
                                                  (actual time=0.024..895.798 rows=10
               Buffers: shared hit=11069
 Planning time: 0.261 ms
 Execution time: 3411.119 ms
```

PostgreSQL doesn't have to sort, but it still scans the whole subquery result and throws away most of the rows.